# Auto-increment a primary key in the LINQ to SQL DataContext "Insert" partial method

Tags: linq-to-sql

What I would like to do is the following. I have a single table, Products, containing a private key ProductID. Instead of having SQL Server auto-increment ProductID on inserts, I want to increment it in the DataContext partial method "InsertProduct":

```
Partial Public Class MyDataContext

    Private Sub InsertProduct(ByVal instance As Product)

        Dim id As Integer = Me.Products.Max(Function(p As Product) p.ProductID) + 1
        instance.ProductID = id

        Me.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance)

    End Sub

End Class
```

However, this will only work when inserting the first Product instance. When attempting to insert a second instance, the id retrieved is the same as for the first,

```
Using context As New MyDataContext

    Dim product1 As New Product
    context.Products.InsertOnSubmit(product1)
    context.SubmitChanges() 'This works

    Dim product2 As New Product
    context.Products.InsertOnSubmit(product2)
    context.SubmitChanges() 'DuplicateKeyException

End Using
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

I would really recommend letting SQL Server do the incremental numbering. The above approach even if you do get it working would fail under load in a multi-user scenario where they both get the same ID and try to insert the same one.

Answer (score 0):

InsertProduct isn't declared as a partial method in the code above.  Is this a typo in your post or have you declared it with a different signature than required and thus it is not being executed?

[EDIT] I'm not a VB programmer (I  use C#),  but  I think your code needs to declare the code as partial as well as in the designer.  This is true in C#, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

InsertProduct is declared as a partial method in the designer generated file (MyDataClasses.designer.vb).

It is executed, in fact I can insert a breakpoint in InsertProduct and observe everything running correctly for product1. For product2 an exception is thrown by `context.SubmitChanges()` but the breakpoint is not hit.