# LINQ to SQL: set PK using DataContext "Insert" partial method

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to achieve something similar to what's described in [this old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275233/auto-increment-a-primary-key-in-the-linq-to-sql-datacontext-insert-partial-meth), which never got a proper answer. I'm trying to find a way to delegate setting the primary key of newly inserted objects to the DataContext InsertX() partial methods when SubmitChanges() is called. Essentially, this makes primary key generation *lazy*, and better separates it from the business logic.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id
    {
        get ...
        set ... // usual linq to sql bodies
    }
}
...
// provide an implementation for the insert overload
public class DB : DataContext
{
    partial void InsertFoo(Foo instance)
    {
        instance.Id = GetNextFooId();
        ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
    }
}
```

This currently fails when inserting more than one object with a DuplicateKeyException, possibly because LINQ to SQL tries to access the primary keys to distinguish instances from each other? I've tried overriding the Equals and GetHashCode to solve this problem, but no dice.

The exception provides no details as to which specific class is causing the problem, and there's no way to log the internal operation of the DataContext, so I'd appreciate any suggestions!

If there's some sort of pre-update event that fires at some point, I could hook into that, but the DataContext Insert overload is the only way I could see. Perhaps LINQ to SQL simply can't express this pattern, as it would need an InsertingFoo/InsertedFoo distinction to mirror the PropertyChanging/PropertyChanged.

Comment: I actually suspect this won't be possible, because any associations access the primary key eagerly to set their FK fields, so setting the PK lazily won't work. If so that's a shame, since setting the PK eagerly pollutes otherwise clean business logic with repetitive code. Furthermore, long-running programs can't complete when short programs run concurrently, since the eager PK init means any PK values read are probably stale.

Comment: Why not just let the database handle all this messy business and use an IDENTITY column in SQL Server?? You save yourself a lot of messy and error-prone code, and it "just works"!

Comment: Because I'm integrating with an existing system, so I don't have the luxury of defining the schema from scratch. Also, there are known performance issues with identity columns, and identity is not portable.